# Why does Powershell think log2(1/2) equals log2(1/2) * 3?

Tags: powershell, syntax

Given a function: 

`function log2 {param ([double]$x) [Math]::Log($x) / [Math]::Log(2) }`

Expected: `log2(45/120) * 2` is interpreted as `(log2(45/120)) * 2` and yields `-2.83007499856`

Actual: `log2(45/120) * 2` equals `log2(45/120)` and yields `-1,41503749927884`
Why is that?

To me, `(log2(1/2) * 3) -eq (log2(1/2))` yielding `True` doesn't make sense.

[Uservoice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/32679241-log2-45-120-2-should-be-interpreted-as-log2-45)

Comment: What does it say `45 / 120` is?

Comment: This is not a bug, you've simply misunderstood powershell's command syntax. The original call to `log2` has to be nested in an subexpression: `(log2 (45/120)) * 3`. Please see `Get-Help about_Parsing`

Comment: People voting to close: How is this *off-topic*?  I can't think of a more on-topic question for PowerShell syntax.  How is, "Can someone explain how this line is parsed?" -- which is what this question is -- how is that off-topic?

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason you call:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows -File
```

And not:

```
Get-ChildItem(-Path, C:\Windows, -File)
```

Remember, *the same command line parser has to handle everything.*

Just because you have a named parameter doesn't mean the standard parsing stops working.

Let's examine your command.

```
log2(45/120) * 2
```

This calls the function `log2`.  The first argument is `(45/120)`.  The second argument is `'*'`, and the third argument is `2`.  The first argument gets assigned to the named parameter, `$x`.  The second argument is unnamed, so it gets assigned to `$args[0]`.  The third argument is unnamed as well, so it gets assigned to `$args[1]`.

Try this:

```
function log2 {param ([double]$x) [Math]::Log($x) / [Math]::Log(2); $args }

log2(45/120) * 2
```

Your output will be:

```
-1.41503749927884
*
2
```

Let's try this function:

```
function Get-ArgumentType { $args | Select-Object @{n='Argument';e={$_}},@{n='Type';e={$_.GetType().FullName}} }

Get-ArgumentType (45/120) * 2
```

The output is:

```
Argument Type
-------- ----
   0.375 System.Double
       * System.String
       2 System.Int32
```

So there are three different arguments, and it didn't recognize `*` as an operator at all.

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense if you use the PowerShell command syntax rather than the function syntax.  I.e. `log2(x)` is the same as `log2 x`.  To specify an expression as the parameter one must place parentheses around it.

```
(log2 45)
(log2 (45/120))
(log2 (45/120)) * 2
```